# Using any of the OpenCV tutorial for face detection Is there any function that calculated the size of the rectangle that is drawn on the face?

Tags: c++, function, opencv, size

Using any of the OpenCV tutorial for face detection,

Is there any function that calculated the size of the rectangle that is drawn on the face?

i'm using C++

i know there is this class (Size_) from the basic structures on the website, but i am not sure  how i could use it.

example:
**as you are moving towards the camera and away from it, the size of the rectangle changes 
i'm trying to display that size**

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: hi, @Zahra, you get a `std::vector<cv::Rect>` from the CascadeClassifier. could you refine your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is easier that you might expect in opencv an cv::Rect is defined by a point and a cv::Size Therefore you can create a Rect by using a size and an point in it's constructor. Note that a cv::Rect is actually a typedef to cv::Rect_ that makes it a bit easier for the user.

```
/*Create a size of 10 by 10*/
cv::Size s ( 10,10);

/*Create a Rect at 10, 10 with the size above*/
cv::Rect r ( cv::Point(10,10), s);
/*And now you can easily obtain the size by using the cv::Size cv::Rect::size()*/
cv::Size new_size = r.size();

std::cout << "width = " << r.width << "\theight = " << r.height << endl;
```